# Flask Alchemy how do I create formatted email column or a column to hold paragraphs for a biography

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to expand a database table from a tutorial. I'm using sqlalchemy in a flask application.

I would like to be able to add all of the columns my little heart desires but at the very least I would like to know if there is a correct way to add:

1. a column to hold a website url
2. a column to hold paragraphs as paragraphs, so probably html but nothing crazy. No links or lists.

Normally I can find anything on google but I've spent hours across two days playing with this and resources are scares. I can't find a list of available columns, column attributes, best practices, or any solid documentation. I've done the same forum tutorial 12 different ways though and none of them go beyond the basic profile information. Any resource you could include would be helpful.

python:

```
id  = db.Column(db.Integer(20), primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(25), unque=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = dbColumn(db.String(20))
    last_name = dbColumn(db.String(20))
    profile_pic = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    bio = db.Column(db.String(500))

    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    community_score = db.Column(db.Integer(3), default=100)
    forum_posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
```

Comment: You wanna validate data before save it on db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy is an extension that uses SQLAlchemy. For information on how to accomplish various tasks you can use the [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/index.html) directly. There are differences but they tend to be minor and documented. Don't limit your google searches to just Flask-SQLAlchemy.

For instance, your questions can pretty much be answered by looking through the various [datatypes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html) and deciding which ones will best suite your needs.

My suggestions:

1. Website URL/Email - Use [String(##)](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.String) and validate using standard python before inserting into the database. Don't use the database to validate.
2. Paragraphs - Use [Text](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Text). It's a string of indefinite length. Use it to store your paragraphs in whatever format you choose (HTML, Plain text, markdown, etc...).

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful.